# Unable to execute ug() graph command in Rstudio

Tags: graph

I am working on the codes from the book "Graphical Models with R", where I installed the gRbase package from Cran and graph package using Bioconductor but unable to execute the first few command.

library(gRbase)

ug(~a:b, ~b:c:d, ~e)

Receive an error unable to find the function ug(). Also the library function gives namespace error when I execute it.  Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can you please add some details on what you have researched and why those answers are unable to assist you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I was using the R version from microsoft (Mran) which does not support many packages, secondly I had R version 4 which gave the above mentioned problem. After installing R 3.6.2, I am now able to execute the commands mentioned above.